# Jeditable show always select box

Tags: jeditable

i'm using the Jeditable plugin to send request to the server by changing the select box. my problem is, that i want to show the select box at any time, not only if the users (double)clicks the text. i did not found any option on the plugin site, so i ask you if there is another solution (for the plugin).

```
$('.col-type').editable( 'set-type.php', {
    data: function(value, settings) {
        return " {'1':'1','2':'2','3':'3', 'selected':'2'}";
    },
    onblur      : "submit",
    type        : "select"
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Idea on [inplace editing](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/inplaceeditor) is to show the form only when you click element. If you always want to show the form use plain old html.

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: of course i could do that, but i thought it would also be possible without an extra onclick function to send the changes.

Comment: It does not make sense to use inline edit plugin if you are just going to use normal form. You can just submit the select value when change event triggers.

http://api.jquery.com/change/